# Implementing Google Places API with updated Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-places-api

Over the past few days, I am trying to find a step - by - step tutorial to implement google places with the updated version of google maps (in eclipse for Android) with no success.

In the old tutorials I find , the  map doesn't appear, because it is not updated in the v2.

Can anyone suggest a way to proceed? I feel lost with all the scattered information I get, and I don't have the experience to change the old examples by myself.

I want to make a simple app, that finds my current location and displays the cafes and restaurants, within 3Km distance. At this point I have tha map showing my location, and I need a tutorial to guide me into implementing Google Places from scratch.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually making an app quite similar to yours! I haven't updated to v2 yet but from what I can tell, the only major difference in implementation is the use of a MapFragment as opposed to a MapActivity.

So you have the map up, yes? Then you should be able to make calls to Google Places the same way you did with the v1 Maps (since they're separate components and don't depend on each other). If Places is what's giving you trouble, I suggest following this tutorial: http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html. It's pretty good and only needs a couple of tweaks to get things up and running.

If you're still having trouble, post back and I might be able to help you out with some code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try and come back with comments.... @Halogen

Comment: .. @Halogen....I couldn't get it to work. I m trying to make this example work http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/ with Google Maps V2, but I haven't managed to do that yet. From what other people told me here, it's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

i found this post helpful,i hope you will find it too,

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-map-setup/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.